# auto_add = True updates with DateTimeField model field, but not DateField

Tags: django, datetime, django-models

I'm using a formset to update a single field of a large group of model instances.  I'd like to display a time stamp showing the time since the field for that instance was last updated.  Since this field will usually be updated once a week, I'd rather use a DateField than a DateTimeField for the time stamp.  DateField doesn't seem to get updated on save though.  When I change the model field to DateTimeField, however, it works as expected.  Here's my code.

```
#Template
<div class = 'last-updated'> {{ form.instance.last_updated|timesince }} </div>

# Models.py
last_updated = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

# Models.py - This version works
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I've found posts saying to override the model's save() method but this seems like a last resort, and the posts I've found saying this are dated from 2011 and earlier, so probably out of date.

Since the docs list DateField and DateTimeField as more or less the same, with the same optional arguments, I'm wondering why they don't seem to update auto_now in the same way.

**Edit**

It also looks as though when I change the field type to DateField, the value displayed is the time since creation, not the time since update, and it updates the value for every single item in the formset.  To clarify, there is NO custom save method for this model.

Comment: Something else is your problem here: this should work. Are you sure you haven't used `auto_now_add`, for example?

Comment: No - that was my first thought as well.  If all I change in my entire program is the field type, it works.  I actually just did this to make sure - it also for some reason changes the value of the time since updated to what looks like the time since created.